# Match patterns to an Sql database by using the jtextfield KeyReleased event that automatically updates the jtable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jtable, jtextfield

I am trying to automatically update a jtable (Table_world)with database contents using the keyReleased event on the jTextfield (tableQuery).

I am using % feature in mysql to do the pattern matching.

However with no luck i am getting the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException 0, when i type a single character to the textfield.

Please tell me what's wrong with my code?

I am using Netbeans GUI Builder for this.

Here is my code pls tell me what's wrong with this.

```
...
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
....
private void tableQueryKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {        
        try {
        String sql = "select empoyeeid, name, surname, age from empoyeeinfo where name LIKE '%?%';";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, tableQuery.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        Table_world.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1101812/3579095

Comment: Got rid of the commas, I am now having this error : SQL error or missing database (near %:error). I even tried:  String sql = "select empoyeeid, name, surname, age from empoyeeinfo where name LIKE %'"+tableQuery.getText()+"'%;"; and got the same error

Comment: @Lars My query works using this code and by pressing any key on the text field:  `String sql = "select empoyeeid, name, surname, age from empoyeeinfo where name LIKE '%mario%';";`  but not when ? is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "%" in the setString method. Like this:

```
pst.setString(1, "%" + yourString +"%");
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the java code for validation of username or email in any java application on KeyReleased events.

I am using Netbeans for my application and mysql as a database.

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tayal_india_pvt_ltd","root","1234");
    ResultSet rs=null;
        String str="select * from login where username like '%"+jTextField6.getText()+"%';";
        PreparedStatement psmt=con.prepareStatement(str);
       rs=psmt.executeQuery();

       if(rs.next()){
     String username=rs.getString("username");
   Pattern p=Pattern.compile(username);
        if (p.matcher(jTextField6.getText()).matches()) {
            jLabel16.setText("Username already exists");
        }
        else{
           jLabel16.setText("");
        } 
       }

con.close();
psmt.close();
     }


            catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
}
```